# Find and Replace String in a text file using Power Shell

Tags: powershell

I have a bat file (say test.bat) which contains some variable assignments like:

`set SFT_HOME=C:\Software1`

`set SFT_ERRO_DIR=C:\Software1\Err`

I need to write a Powershell script to replace these variable values in the test.bat to something like :
`replace 'set SFT_HOME=C:\Software1' with 'set SFT_HOME=C:\Software1\Check'`

`replace 'set SFT_ERRO_DIR=C:\Software1\Err' with 'set SFT_ERRO_DIR=C:\Software1\Err\Check'`

I tried the following but did not work:

`(Get-Content -path C:\program\software\test.bat) -replace 'set SFT_HOME=C:\Software1', 'set SFT_HOME=C:\Software1\Check' | Set-Content C:\program\software\test.bat"`

It gives a **Invalid regular expression pattern** error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are special characters in regex that need to be escaped, specifically the backslash. To escape them you use a backslash - it would look like this

```
 'set SFT_HOME=C:\Software1' -replace 'set SFT_HOME=C:\\Software1','set SFT_HOME=C:\Software1\Check'
```

However, to avoid manually escaping, you can simply use the regex escape() method.

```
'set SFT_HOME=C:\Software1' -replace [regex]::escape('set SFT_HOME=C:\Software1'),'set SFT_HOME=C:\Software1\Check'
```

Comment: Thanks much.. This actually works when I run the command from the powershell prompt... however when i try to call these from a batch script by writing `Powershell command "(Get-Content -path C:\Software1\test.bat) -replace [regex]::escape('set SFT_HOME=C:\Software1'), 'set SFT_HOME=C:\Software1\Check' | Set-Content C:\Software1\test.bat"` , it gives me an error **Get-Command : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Name'.**

Comment: I don’t see Get-Command so are you sure that’s the code that created the error?